# How can I create a Windows Control Library project in Visual Studio?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates

i was trying to complete a tutorial on custom controls and all of the tutorials that ive found say that you have to choose a project template called "windows control library". I don't have that template as an option! I am using VS2010 professional. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ["Windows Control Library" project template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kdceywt.aspx) is used to quickly get started creating custom controls for use in Windows Forms (WinForms) applications. It creates a project that is automatically populated with the necessary references and files.

1. To create a new project of this type, you first have to pick one of the .NET languages—it doesn't matter which—either C#, VB.NET or C++/CLI.
2. Then, select the "Windows" category to narrow down the scope of the project types that are listed.
3. Finally, select the project type called "Windows Forms Control Library".

[image]

Comment: yeeah... i read that tutorial too. i dont have that option :S

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: That's *very* strange. That screenshot is from Visual Studio 2010 Professional, which is the same version you said you're running. You might try re-running the setup program to make sure that you've installed all of the components.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft "walkthrough" (assuming you are looking at the same one found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)) is not very detailed on how to "Add a Windows Forms Control Library project to the solution".
The word "Add" makes me think I would use that keyword in the right-click menu for the existing project but that doesn't help unless you click on the ***solution*** and choose *New Project*.  In other words, you will have more than one project in the solution if this step is followed correctly.