# Not finding Windows Forms Control Library

Tags: vb.net, dll, control-library

I'm trying to create a Windows Forms Control Library using Visual Basic .Net 2010. When I create a New Project, I do not see this type of template as available.

I have found an older post here showing the user how to browse on the left hand side of the New Project dialog box to find the relevant template, but unfortunately this didn't help:

[Creating a Windows Control Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804897/how-can-i-create-a-windows-control-library-project-in-visual-studio)

I also attempted to select Online template in New Project, I have looked under Windows Forms and under Visual Studios but I can't find in either category.

How Can I see and select this template ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your window? The window: New Project > Visual Basic > Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this one is missing in the Express edition.  There isn't anything special about the project template.  Just create a regular class library and add references to System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms.  And add a UserControl.