# How to create a project of windows control library in VS 2012 express?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How to create a project of windows control library in VS 2012 express? I am unable to find this option.only option I have right now are winform,cosole,WPF & class lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kzfy8za(v=vs.90).aspx.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The express edition doesn't contain a template for the windows control library.  You can still create one by making a regular class library with references to System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672185/3033053

Comment: not working....! getting error as below:   
getting error for last imported namespace & for base class.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace ClockControl
{
    public class ClockControl : UserControl
    {

    }
}